# Is it possible to renew long lived access token in Facebook using an api call?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook documentation states that

. At any point, you can generate a new long-lived token by sending the person back to the login flow used by your web app - **note that the person will not actually need to login again**, they have already authorized your app, so they will immediately redirect back to your app from the login flow with a refreshed token - how this appears to the person will vary based on the type of login flow that you are using, for example if you are using the JavaScript SDK, this will take place in the background, if you are using a server-side flow, the browser will quickly redirect to the Login Dialog and then automatically and immediately back to your app again.

What does it mean that the person does not actually need to login? Does not he have to pass his credentials again? If not how does FB is authenticating the user and getting the refreshed access token?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you need that the user visits your web app. Then you check for login status, if it is "connected" you will get a new short-lived token without even making the user login again. That's because the token has information about apps already authorized by user. If not the case or the user hasn't login in FB then you need to call the login function.

Once you have the token you can create a new long-lived token again.